# Can I set a particular resolution for whenever I plug my laptop into a secondary display?

Tags: windows-10, display

Right now, my laptop has a 3200 x 1800 resolution and is scaled at 250 percent. I would like the display on the secondary display to be 100 percent at 1920 x 1080 whenever it is plugged in to the secondary display.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a resolution in the registry
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/VIDEO
Identify the 2nd monitor by its resolution & input the desired resolution
The scaling issue has already been answered here: [separate custom scaling levels for each display in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1022273/separate-custom-scaling-levels-for-each-display-in-windows-10)